# getimagesize on dynamic image

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, getimagesize

I have a MySQL table in which I store user avatars as a blob. I fetch those images with a script called avatar.php which outputs the image. To request a specific user image, you have to call avatar.php?id=(user id). To make the dynamic image name pretty, I added an URL rewrite in my .htaccess so you can also call avatar-(userid).jpg, which will translate in avatar.php?id=(userid).

Now I want to fetch the user image and manipulate it using GD. I tried using getimagesize() and imagecreatefromjpeg() but I'm continuously getting an "failed to open stream no such file or directory" error.. Both the script in which I try to use these functions, as the avatar.php script, are in the root directory. I tried:

```
getimagesize('avatar.php?id=1');
getimagesize('./avatar.php?id=1');
getimagesize('/avatar.php?id=1');
...and the same but using avatar-1.jpg instead.
```

When I use the full url of my site (including http:// etc.) it actually works... But I haven't found out why.

//**Edit**:
Similar problem occurs when using the file_exists() function. If I try file_exists('./avatar.php') it returns true, if I add get-vars it returns false. Are these functions unsuitable for dynamic files?

Could someone help me out please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load the image string directly from your database into a variable ... not via getimagesize('avatar.php?id=1');
2. Use [imagecreatefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to load your image as an image object. Afterwards you can manipulate your image and send it to your output.

If you just want the image size without any manipulation you can use [getimagesizefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesizefromstring.php)

Answer (score 2):

`getimagesize` expects a ***file path***. `getimagesize('avatar.php?id=1')` tries to open the file `avatar.php?id=1` on the local hard disk, which of course doesn't exist.
If you use `getimagesize('http://example.com/avatar.php?id=1')`, it is understood that the path is a URL and it will go through the HTTP wrapper. Basically, `getimagesize` will still think it's opening a local file, but PHP will fetch that file through an HTTP request in the background. Since that HTTP request is actually returning a valid image file, that works.
Of course you do *not* want to engage your web server every time you're trying to open an image, as that's an unnecessary waste of resources. In fact, even if `getimagesize('avatar.php?id=1')` would work the way you think it does, that's still a lot of overhead for what you're trying to do.

If your images are stored in the database, figure out the image dimensions *once* when you put the image into the database and store them in a database column. Then simply query the size from the database.

---

> Similar problem occurs when using the file_exists() function. If I try
>   `file_exists('./avatar.php')` it returns true, if I add get-vars it
>   returns false. Are these functions unsuitable for dynamic files?

All these functions expect ***file paths***. `avatar.php` is a valid file name/path. `avatar.php?foo=bar` is *not* a valid file name/path. The latter is (part of) a URL. URLs have nothing to do with the local file system. They're only handled through a web server, which may or may not invoke a PHP or some other file on the disk. You need to distinguish the concept of *file paths* and *URLs*.

Comment: I was talking about getimagesize as an example. Actually I'm temporarily storing a large image in the database, which I want to load through imagecreatefromjpeg to make a thumbnail of it and store it in another column in the database. In other words, I have to fetch the image from the database, manipulate it with GD and then store it back into the database again.

Comment: Yes, and I hope I have cleared up your confusion regarding file paths/URLs. `imagecreatefromjpeg` expects a file path as well. If you're getting the image from a database, you won't have it on disk as a file and it won't work either. You need to use `imagecreatefromstring` then.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `getimagesize` tries to open the php file, not the "image" the php file would output when parsed and executed.

This is also the reason why the full URL works: your script *requests* the output from your webserver, and the webserver executes the script (loading the image from DB and outputting it).

Loading it through the webserver (with full URL) might still be the simplest option.

You could also create an image resource with `imagecreatefromstring` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)), giving the function your results from the DB and then manipulate that.